# Nested jQuery AJAX ends up in the error case, but there was no errors and everything worked fine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function()
{
    $('#add_comment').bind('submit',function()
    //$("input[type=submit]").click(function()
    {
        var problem_id = $("#problem_id").val();
        var problem_comment = $("#problem_comment").val();  

        var dataString = 'problem_id='+ problem_id + '&problem_comment=' + problem_comment;

        if( problem_id == '' || problem_comment == '' )
        {   
            $('.comment_success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.comment_error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {   
            // Now check if the person is logged in.
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/auth/check_login.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        // Now add the comment!
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/problems/add_problem_comment_ajax.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: dataString ,
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                $('.add_message_success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                $('.add_message_error').fadeOut(200).hide();

                                // Here can update the right side of the screen with the newly entered information
                                alert ("success");


                            },
                            error: function(data)
                            {
                                alert ("add comment error, data: " + data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(json)
                    {
                        $("#loginpopup").dialog();

                        return false;           
                    }
            });         
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

It actually works fine, and calls the AJAX in both places, and the server code behaves as I want it to behave, and I am happy with how it works.

Unfortunately, the nested jQuery AJAX call always goes back into the error case.  I don't know why.  How can I get to understand why it does that?

I get no errors in the JavaScript console of Chrome or in my PHP server logs.  Any idea what it could be?

Also, how can I tell what is in the data variable that is returned? The way I output it now it just says "Object object"

Thanks!!

Comment: Why the second ajax? can't you do that right on the first call? Using the second file though, you make the check there

Comment: @DamienPirsy I wasn't aware you can do that within one call.  I mean, I need to call two different AJAX scripts.

Comment: Using `console.log("Add comment error. Data", data)` instead of `alert()` will give you some more insight. It outputs into the JavaScript console, which can often be opened using Ctrl-Shift-J, but can also be found in Firebug (if you have that installed).

Comment: @GeekedOut AJAX script is a php file, in which you can do whatever you want. Think of the times when AJAX wasn't used, you would have done everything server side, so: you could either split them into two different calls, or group into one that does everything; this way you won't face this kind of problem of nexted ajax; you could always browse jquery's source to see how it handles the call, anyway, and see if your implementation is possible, or check for error logs that actually tell you what and where's going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your error function as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error : function (xhr, status, error){
        // Error Text //
        console.log(xhr.responseText); // Server Response
        console.log(xhr.statusText); // Server Status Response
        console.log(error); // Thrown Error

        // Data Object //
        console.log(data); // Displayed in console.
    }
    ...
});
```

The xhr object is part of the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object.

All info will appear in the javascript console.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ah, you know, that made things more clear.  I do get a 200 code back, which means its successful.  But in the responseText I get text back that I am trying to have outputed back in the page.  I am using the PHP echo command to display the HTML.  In other parts of the site that technique worked, so not exactly sure why it doesn't work now.

Comment: @GeekedOut Have you tried console.log(status) and console.log(error) to see if they contain any info?